# Assigning base struct to derived struct

Tags: c++

I use a struct to represent data that is written to a file. If I need to add members to this struct (i.e. save out extra data) I create a new struct (this represents a new version of the dataset) that derives from the original one. So for example:

```
struct data1
{
   int stuff1;
   int stuff2;
};

struct data : data1
{
   int stuff3;
};
```

Backward compatibility is maintained by checking if we're loading `data1`, and if so, convert it to `data` (and value-initialize only those new members in `data`). What would be the best way to do this? Here is what I've started:

```
if( loaded_data.size() == sizeof(data1) ) {
    // Old data format detected, upgrade to new structure
    data d = data(); // value-initialize everything
    // TODO: Assign 'data1' to 'data'
}
```

I've thought of putting a constructor in `data` to copy from a `data1`, but then that breaks the free value-initialization I get (I'd have to implement my own default constructor at that point). Should I use memcpy(), or is there a better more built-in way (perhaps some trick with copy semantics)?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  There's an enormous number of serialization libraries out there already -- Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) are a great example.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Your comment is off-topic, but this is code that's already there and can't be changed. I'm not asking for different serialization techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the design, I believe you should not inherit (this, for example, makes your type not be an aggregate), and that there are better approaches to serialization/deserialization than checking the size of the entity. That being said, after you force the initialization you can just assign. The implicitly declared copy constructor will be defined and the members will be copied:

```
data d = { 1, 2 };         // Can use this as it is an aggregate
data1 d1 = data1();
d1 = d;
```

Again, I would avoid this altogether...

If instead of inheritance you used composition, then you could use aggregate initialization and avoid the double initialization of the base in `data1`:

```
struct data1 {
  data base;
  int extra;
};
data d   = { 1, 2 };
data1 d1 = { d, 5 };   // or { d, 0 }
```

> I've thought of putting a constructor in data to copy from a data1, but then that breaks the free value-initialization I get (I'd have to implement my own copy & default constructors at that point).

Not completely true. You will need to provide a default constructor, as the presence of the constructor taking `data` will inhibit the implicit declaration of a default constructor. But the copy constructor will still be implicitly generated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I stated to you earlier, this system is fixed and cannot be changed (and such is outside the scope of this question). But yeah, this is definitely not something I like...

Comment: @RobertDailey: Note that the question title is incorrect. POD is a subcategory of *aggregate*, and a type is not an *aggregate* if it has a base type, which in turn means that your derived type is **not** a POD. That being said, does this not answer your question? (i.e. first block of code)

Comment: This is true, that fact had slipped my mind. Hard to remember every little detail in the standard sometimes. I wasn't aware that the compiler generated copy assignment for base class types in derived types (at least that seems to be what you're implying).

Comment: Inheriting structs is a good solution when you get bad quality code and need to improve it. Make a child struct, add what you need, ready.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
  int a;
};

struct B : A {
  int b;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.a = 42; 
  B b;
  b.a = 0;
  b.b = 42;
  (A&)b = a;

  printf("%s\n", b.a == b.b?"it works":"nope");
}
```

Comment: It would be nice, if you would elaborate a bit on your code.

Comment: the check should be `b.a == a.a`

Answer (score 1):

You want to have the default ctors for your members, but still want to be able to exploit the default copy ctor. I suppose you could do this with composition.

```
struct Data1 {
  /**/
};

struct Data2 { // this is your extension
  /**/
};

struct Data3 { // possibly the next extension.
  /**/
};

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct ExtendData : Base, Derived {
  ExtendData(Base const& base, Derived const& derived)
    : Base(base), Derived(derived) {}
};

typedef ExtenData<Data1,Data2> FullData2;
typedef ExtenData<FullData2,Data3> FullData3;
```

This allows you to use all default constructors of your POD `struct`s:

```
FullData2 data2 = {Base{/**/},Derived{/**/}};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid/hide the ugliness of `memcpy()`, you can create global functions to initialize your structures - inside these functions you can then use `memcpy()` or simply assign fields one-by-one.

This way if your initialization semantics ever changes, you only need to update your initializer functions and you keep your structures clean of member functions (that is, they'll still look like plain data structures if that's what you prefer/need). For example:

```
void InitData ( data& oData, data1& oInitializer )
{
    memcpy ( ... );
}
```

You can override this function for each new type as you keep adding new members and new structures.

If you prefer a (somewhat) more C++-like approach, you can turn these functions into public static members of your `data` structure. You'd then call it something like

```
data::InitFrom ( data1 );
```

This allows you to keep your structures clean (no virtual functions, etc.), but you still get better type safety and the low-level details are still hidden from the rest of your code. These gloal/static functions would also keep the current sematics of your structures.

Keep in mind, though, that C++ purists would probably dislike this option.